# Use of "any" in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How would you translate these two sentences into predicate logic?

"X does not know anything" vs. "x does not know everything?"

Both sentences seem quite similar. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\know}{\mathop{\rm know}\nolimits}$
"Any" is a bit tricky.

In the context of negation, "not any" usually translates as "no(thing)":

> X does *not* know *anything*
>   = X knows *nothing*

Without negation, "any" can mean "every(thing)":

> *Any* child can do this with a bit of help.
>   = *Every* child can do this with a bit of help.

And sometimes it means "some(thing)":

> Pick *any* of the cards.
>   = Pick *some (no matter which)* of the cards.

What *any* means in a particular context is more of a question of English linguistics than logic. You will have to rely on your intuition to find that out.

---

In any case, "all" or "every(thing)" translates as $\forall x \phi$:

> "I know *everything*"
>   $\forall x (\know(i,x))$

Correspondingly, a negated "every" translates as $\neg \forall x \phi$, which is equivalent to $\exists x \neg \phi$:

> "I do *not* know *everything*"
>   $\neg \forall x (\know(i,x))$
>   "There is *something* that I do *not* know"
>   $\exists x \neg (\know(i,x))$

"No(thing)" translates as $\neg \exists x \phi$ or, equivalently, $\forall x \neg \phi$:

> "I do *not* know *anything*"
>   $\neg \exists x (\know(i,x))$
>   "For *all* things it holds that I do *not* know them"
>   $\forall x \neg (\know(i,x))$

And finally, "some(thing)" translate as $\exists x \phi$:

> "I know *something*"
>   $\exists x (\know(i,x))$

---

So your two sentences are not that similar:

> "I don't know anything"

is

> "There doesn't exist a thing I know"
>   $\neg \exists x (\know(i,x))$
>   or equivalently
>   "For all things it holds that I do not know them"
>   $\forall x \neg (\know(i,x))$

whereas

> "I don't know everything"

is

> "Not for all things it holds that I know them"
>   $\neg \forall x (\know(i,x))$
>   which is equivalent to
>   "There exists a thing that I don't know"
>   $\exists x \neg (\know(i,x))$

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence means “for every piece of knowledge, X is unware of it”, whereas the second one means “the is some piece of knowledge of which X is unaware”. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would translate the first one as $\forall x\neg K(x)$ and the second one as $\exists x\neg K(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Both the sentences are not similar, at least by its meaning. And, secondly, a predicate is just a boolean-valued function, which indicates that either a statement is true or false. So from a mathematical point, both the statements are different and can be both true or false or one of them can be true.

Comment: The fact that a predicate is a boolean-valued function does not mean that any to syntactically different strings must have independent truth values.